# Django rest aggregation validation

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, aggregate

I have a `Ticket` model and a `Product` model and I want to make sure it is not possible to change the amount of tickets available for the product to less than the amount of tickets there are already sold. To achieve this I'm using aggregate queries in the serializer update method.

However, in order to use the aggregate queries for this specific instance you need to set the `pk` to `read_only=False` (als tom christie himself advised: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2320 ). This opens up another problem however because now I have to make sure it is not possible for people to change the `pk`. Does anyone know how to achieve this or implement aggregate validation another way so I do not have to expose the `pk` of my `Product` model?

Here is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class Ticket(models.Model):
    buyername = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    buyeremail = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='tickets')
```

This is my Product serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer ):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=False)
    name = serializers.CharField(min_length=3,max_length=50)
    amount = serializers.IntegerField(min_value = 0,max_value = 100)
    price = serializers.DecimalField(min_value=1.0,max_value=1001.0,max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    ticketssold = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.amount = validated_data['amount']
        #get the amount of tickets sold
        filtered_data = Product.objects.filter(pk=validated_data['pk']).aggregate(Count('tickets'))
        if instance.amount < filtered_data['tickets__count']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("It is not possible to update the amount of tickets to less tickets than there are sold!")
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: I could be wrong but doesn't the `read_only=False` concerns only `ListSerializers`? You are not able to get the `pk` from `instance.pk`? Or even access `instance.tickets`?

Comment: Indeed it is not possible to acces this directly. But because you set read_only=False it does get passed into the dictionary validated_date. And ,as you can see in my code, you can retrieve it using `pk=validated_data['pk']`